# Connecting jhipster (spring boot+angular) application to a keycloak with https

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak

I am trying to connect a basic jhipster application to a keycloak instance thats using https. I want to keycloak to handle authentication for the jhipster app.

I have no issues connecting the two systems when performing authentication over http. I created realms, clients, roles and can sucessfully have the jhipster sign-in button redirect to keycloak. Then when the user puts in the credentials the user is returned to the jhipster app logged in.

I have done this by populating the security section in the src/main/resources/config/application.yml file in the jhipster project.

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://my-test-keycloak.com/auth/realms/jhipster
        registration:
          oidc:
            client-id: jhipster-client
            client-secret: jhipster-client
```

I have attempted to now connect to a keycloak instance running https but I am getting errors when trying to run my jhipster application.

I have tried the following changes:

- I changed issuer-uri: https://my-test-keycloak.com/auth/realms/jhipster
- added dependencies for 'keycloak-spring-boot-starter'
- added yml for spring boot adapter in application.yml
- put the public certificate 'my-test-keycloak-com.pem in truststore.jks

```
keycloak:
  realm: jhipster
  auth-server-url: https://my-test-keycloak.com/auth
  resource: jhipster-client
  truststore : path/to/truststore.jks
  truststore-password : mytruststorepassword
```

Errors that i am receiving

```
ERROR 95593 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration' defined in file [/jhipster-test/target/classes/com/test/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "https://my-test-keycloak/auth/realms/jhipster"
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://my-test-keycloak/auth/realms/jhipster/.well-known/openid-configuration": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:651)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.lambda$oidc$0(ClientRegistrations.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrations.getBuilder(ClientRegistrations.java:192)
    ... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1967)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:331)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1688)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:1010)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1079)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1388)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1416)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:167)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:739)
```